# Using class-based UpdateView on a m-t-m with an intermediary model

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

How can I convince a Django 1.3 class based generic view:

```
UpdateView.as_view(model=Category,
template_name='generic_form.html',
success_url='/category/')
```

To not give up so easy with error:

```
"Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model."
```

Even if all fields in the intermediary model have defaults, I can't get the class based generic view to save.  The functional based version looks messy also.  Django 1.3.

Comment: Note I used admin.TabularInlin to make the editing work in the admin.

Answer (score 2):

As Berislav Lopac says:

```
class CategoryView(UpdateView):
    model=Category
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        IntermediateModel.objects.filter(category = self.object).delete()
        for other_side_model_object in form.cleaned_data['other_side_model_field']:
            intermediate_model = IntermediateModel()
            intermediate_model.category = self.object
            intermediate_model.other_side_model_related_field= other_side_model_object
            intermediate_model.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

I answer some similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745652/2165413).

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `UpdateView` and override the `form_valid()` method to manually save the intermediary model.

Personally, I never use generic views directly from the URL pattern, I always extend them verbatim in `views.py`.

Comment: I'm a novice to django, could you be more explicit or show a sample?

Comment: It makes zero sense to copy/paste code from generic views.  Would not recommend.

Comment: Where did you get copy/paste from?