# How to save the created object with a many-to-many relationship and map table?

Tags: python, mysql, django, many-to-many

Using the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745652/1080402) in [Class-based views for M2M relationship with intermediate model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224442/class-based-views-for-m2m-relationship-with-intermediate-model/15745652#15745652), I am able to save the `Membership` if I hard code an ID for its foreignkey to `Group`, despite not having any information for `date_joined` and `invite_reason`, but the `Group` for which the form is filled out never gets saved, and therefore I cannot supply `Membership` with the correct ID. In fact, any time I try to save the`group`, before or after the code in the accepted answer, I get the same `AttributeError` as the OP:

> Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use Membership's Manager instead.

Is there a way to make this code actually work? Am I being led astray? What would be the proper way to save something with a many-to-many field that goes through a mapping table? The answers I've found have confused me more than helped me.

For reference, should the question ever be deleted:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

**Accepted Answer** (With an additional line to hard code an ID)

```
from django.views.generic.edit import ModelFormMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class GroupCreate(CreateView):
    model = Group

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        for person in form.cleaned_data['members']:
            membership = Membership()
            membership.group = self.object
            membership.group_id = 108 # Added line
            membership.person = person
            membership.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Note: I had to add the id line because I would get the following `IntegrityError` without it:

> Column 'group_id' cannot be null

In case it's pertinent, I am trying to save this to a MySQL database.