# how to save many to many fields in django create view

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-generic-views

Here is my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True,default=None)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )
    .....

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, through='CatToPost')
     .......

class CatToPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

The problem now I can't make it work to save the many-to-many field by using the generic create view.

> Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary
>   model.  Use posts.CatToPost's Manager instead.

In SO there was a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745652/1310740) that suggest override the `form_valid` method to manually create the relation, but it didn't works for me.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        for cat in form.cleaned_data['categories']:

            cate = CatToPost()
            cate.post = self.object
            cate.category = cat
            cate.save()
        return super(AddStoryForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

The error:

> Cannot assign "": "Post" instance isn't saved
>   in the database.

Seem `self.object = form.save(commit=False)` not saving in the db, so the Post ID wasn't created.

But when I turn `self.object = form.save(commit=True)` , I still got the previous error occurred again.

Any idea how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem to the answer you listed. For me what worked is to add `self.object.save()` after `self.object = form.save(commit=False)`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.save()

    for cat in form.cleaned_data['categories']:

        cate = CatToPost()
        cate.post = self.object
        cate.category = cat
        cate.save()
    return super(AddStoryForm, self).form_valid(form)
```